# install4j Add/Remove item not getting removed

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to create our installers.

In "Register Add/Remove item" action of the base installer, we set the Item name to be "${compiler:sys.fullName}".

Under General Settings, Full Name has been set to: "PRODUCT NAME ${compiler:sys.version}".

During installation of the base version, the Add Remove Programs dialog works as expected.

Now, in the Add On Installer for this product, we have another "Register Add/Remove item" so that ARP reflects the updated version number. When the Add On installer is installed, the previous ARP entry is replaced by the new one as expected. However when the product is finally uninstalled, the updated ARP entry is not getting removed. I believe this was working properly in our earlier versions.

We are using install4j 5.1.11.

thanks
Parag Thakur

Answer (score 0):

> Now, in the Add On Installer for this product, we have another
>   "Register Add/Remove item" so that ARP reflects the updated version
>   number

An Add-on installer cannot change the version number and the use of the "Register Add/Remove item" action in the Add-on installer is not supported and may lead to unintended consequences like this.

To change the version number, you have to use a full installer.

Comment: No, the add-on installer could never change the version number.

Comment: We don't change the product version in Add-on installer. We are simply changing the text that shows up in ARP to indicate the patch level. This works OK.

Observation:
- If the full installer was created using 5.1.5, but Add-On was created using 5.1.11, this issue surfaces.
- However if both the full installer and the Add-On installer are created using 5.1.11, ARP entry is properly removed.

I am not pursuing a fix since most of our customers will upgrade to the full installer created using 5.1.11.